# Can i use netoffice package to automate outlook application from a web application. Is there any disadvantages

Tags: outlook, netoffice

Can i use netoffice package to automate outlook application from a web application. I need to open outlook window to create meetings and send from a web application.Is there any disadvantages in using netoffice for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It is not a supported way of automating Office applications.

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

If you deal with Exchange profiles you may consider using EWS, see [Get started with EWS Managed API client applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.